Validação de campo de input para nao ultrapassar valor incialmente recebido
Estou usando vue e vuetfy e preciso validar um campo do input para que o valor digitado nele não ultrapasse o valor que ele está inicialmente recebendo do banco de dados.
Como posso fazer isso? Alem de estar digitando qualquer valor ele ainda está ultrapassando as casas numericas...
<v-text-field
        label="Valor a pagar"
        outlined
        item-text="alias"
        v-money="money"
        v-model="bill.valorReceber"
        :rules="[$rules.required, $rules.validMinValue]"
      />


Fiz uma pesquisa, abaixo mandarei uma pośsível solução:

Armazene o Valor inicial do Banco de Dados: você pode fazer isso utilizando uma variável Vue. Ela servirá como referência para a validação.
Valide usando o Vuetify: Use a diretiva "v-validate" do Vuetify para aplicar uma regra de validação personalizada ao campo de entrada.
(Sugestão) Exiba uma mensagem de erro: Utilize a diretiva "v-if" do Vuetify para condicionar a exibição de uma mensagem de erro.


Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas na Central de Ajuda.

https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8842/conte%c3%bado-gerado-por-chatgpt-e-similares-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-permitido-no-stack-overflow-em-por?cb=1
